Send data to all sockets at exact time
Say we have array or list of sockets named (A,B,C) and we want to send data to all of them at the same exact time due to that the application is really time critical, then is there a away to send to all of them without iteration? as with iteration then "C" received messages will be always delayed compared to "A" for example.
...
UPDATE:
Paralle.ForEach did the job with 3-4 times faster that normal foreach, here is a benchmark with 20 tries for sending to 5000 sockets:


I am not expert for that matter but, as far as I know you can't. I suggest signalR.

"The exact same time" is not possible using individual sockets. Even if you do the socket sends at the same moment you're network hardware will likely serialize the sends before they are transmitted. This sounds like an XY problem, but perhaps a broadcasting solution might work better if the data is identical.

Even if you can send messages at the same exact time, how do you ensure they will receive them at the same exact time?

In trading apps, your app should guarantee fair play as possible between all sockets by sending on same time for all, and Parallel.ForEach seems perform 3-4 times faster as per @mrSoh solution, see my reply below with 20 tries benchmark for sending to 5000 sockets.

Since you included no code with your question, there was (and is) no way to know what the bottleneck is.

As far as I know (and I could be wrong), you can use Parallel.Foreach() from System.Threading.Tasks so you can execute or process each iteration concurrently.
For example let's say you have a List<Socket> sockets and some dataToSend:
 Parallel.ForEach(sockets, socket =>
        {
            try
            {
                socket.Send(dataToSend);
                Console.WriteLine($"Data sent on thread {Task.CurrentId}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        });

